# Outlook doesn't understand specific rules of my inline code

Tags: html, css, outlook, inline-code

My code is ready, all is good except a thing.
Event if the body have the rule `width:600px;` Outlook doesn't understand, same for the `background-color: rgb(67, 153, 186);`.

Can someone help me please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Newsletter</title>
</head>

<body style="flex-direction: column;rgb(67, 153, 186); max-width: 600px; background-color: rgb(67, 153, 186); font-family: "Univers LT 45", sans-serif;">
   <div style="background-color:rgb(67, 153, 186);">
    <div>
        <h1 style="color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">News</h1>
        <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);width: 100%;margin-bottom: auto;overflow: hidden;">
        <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Geschäftsverlauf / Déroulement des affaires</h1>
        <div style="float: left;width: 50%;">
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Offerten</h1>
            <h2 style="h2 {font-weight: bold;}">Klingen</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p >
            <h2>Boden</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>Abfall</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>UVP</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>Physikalische und Bauakustik</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Projekte</h1>
            <h2>Klingen</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: right;width: 50%;}">
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Offres</h1>
            <h2>Bruit</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>Sols</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>Déchets</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>EIE</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
            <h2>Physique et acoustique du bâtiment</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p >
            <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Projets</h1>
            <h2>Bruit</h2>
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-direction: column;">
        <h1 style="color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Personal / Personnel</h1>
        <h2>Neueinstellungen / Nouveaux engagements</h2>
        <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        <h2>Austritte / Départs</h2>
        <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        <h2>Jubiläum / Jubilé</h2>
        <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        <h2>Geburtstage / Anniversaires</h2>
        <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0); overflow: hidden;">
        <h1 style="color: rgb(67, 153, 186); background-color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">QSUM/MQSE</h1>
        <div style="float: left;width: 50%;">
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: right;width: 50%;}">
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h1 style="color: rgb(214, 196, 0);">Diverses / Divers</h1>
        <div style="float: left;width: 50%;">
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: right;width: 50%;}">
            <p style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dictum, urna nec vulputate molestie, neque leo ultricies mi, ut dignissim magna magna vitae ex. Nunc eu massa purus. Vivamus velit lacus, vulputate a neque ut, faucibus tincidunt elit. Sed volutpat, nunc quis vulputate sagittis, ipsum metus elementum enim, sed ornare velit elit ac nibh.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try adding a div.container and add all of the body properties to div.container. This way the container will act as a body container and should be read correctly by mailing services...

Comment: Outlook doesn't support RGBA as I recall - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ And I'm certain it doesn't support flexbox